# Unable to install pgrouting for postgres 9.3.5/postgis 2.1.7

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I am running postgres 9.3.5 and postgis 2.1.7 on Ubuntu Server 14.10. I am trying to install pgrouting, but having no luck.

1) I tried the following based in the [official workshop documentation](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html):

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:georepublic/pgrouting
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pgrouting
```

Then I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.3-pgrouting
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.3-pgrouting'
```

2) I tried using the UbuntuGIS repo as well, but had no luck.

Any idea how to install pgrouting on my setup? I suspect that this is a Utopic Unicorn issue, but not sure.

Comment: This documentation you linked doesn't seem to be working properly?

Comment: Try these instructions - but they are for v9.4 http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt

Comment: Link corrected. Thanks for noticing. The osgeo doc seems to offer the same commands as the workshop link I provided.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 support has ended, see http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2015/07/03/ubuntu-14-10-utopic-unicorn-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-23-2015/ . Launchpad does not allow to build (upload) packages for unsupported releases, so pgRouting packages for 14.10 are not maintained anymore either.